# iPhone App crashes (EXC_BAD_ACCESS) on editing any textfield in main

Tags: xcode, ios4, exc-bad-access

I am a bit new to the iPhone, but I have done some work on the Mac before. In my App there is a text field. And if I´m editing this text field, the App crashes after a few types, and there is an an EXC_BAD_ACCESS sign in main. I have added an other textfield, right in the standart view. It crashes, too, although I have not done anything with it. I have no idea, and I killed every release, so that nothing is overreleased, bit it does not help. Has anyone an idea? thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer. It´s a bug in iPhone Simulator. I had to turn off autocorrecting. Then it worked.

Comment: Turning off the autocorrect within the simulator settings fixed it for me too.

Answer (score 0):

Are you working with XCode 4.1? This is a problem related to that version, I just downloaded the Xcode 4.1.1 from the App Store and the problem went away completely.

Regards

Comment: I just had the same issue (and the same solution) in 4.2